# Android Studio Lint does not recognize AppCompatActivity as subclass of FragmentActivity

Tags: java, android, kotlin, androidx, static-analysis

My MainActivity is a subclass of AppCompatActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
```

And in some places in the code I use functions and properties of FragmentActivity, like `invalidateMenu()` and `onBackPressedDispatcher`.

**Everything compiles just fine and works just fine.**
The only issue is that Android Studio lint does not recognize AppCompatActivity as derived from FragmentActivity.

I have not encountered any other issues with lint in my code, but this issue does happen in any activity where I use FragmentActivity functions and properties in a subclass of AppCompatActivity.

Unresolved:
[image: unresolved1]

Resolved (cast just for testing):
[image: resolved1]

Unresolved:
[image: unresolved2]

Resolved (cast just for testing):
[image: resolved2]

Problems window:
[image: problems]

### EDIT- More information:

A sequence of ctrl+click on AppCompatActivity takes me eventually to `...gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.core\core\1.0.0...` where

```
public class ComponentActivity extends Activity
        implements LifecycleOwner, KeyEventDispatcher.Component {
```

A ctrl+click on onBackPressedDispatcher with the cast test takes me to
`...gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.activity\activity\1.7.1\...` where

```
public class ComponentActivity extends androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity implements
        ContextAware,
        LifecycleOwner,
        ViewModelStoreOwner,
        HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory,
        SavedStateRegistryOwner,
        OnBackPressedDispatcherOwner,
        ActivityResultRegistryOwner,
        ActivityResultCaller,
        OnConfigurationChangedProvider,
        OnTrimMemoryProvider,
        OnNewIntentProvider,
        OnMultiWindowModeChangedProvider,
        OnPictureInPictureModeChangedProvider,
        MenuHost,
        FullyDrawnReporterOwner {
```

Comment: Can you include your `dependencies` block from your `build.gradle`? Do you only have a dependency on `AppCompat` or do you have an explicit dependency on a specific version of Fragment and Activity?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Following your comment I removed almost everything with androidx from my app build.gradle. I kept only androidx.navigation. Cleared build and cache. Somehow everything still compiles perfectly. But the issue remains.

Comment: I think you need to do the opposite, actually: have an explicit dependency on the AppCompat, Fragment, and Activity versions you want to be using.

Comment: "androidx.activity:activity:1.7.1", "androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.1" "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.7.1", did not solve it. I actually do not know why is it using 1.7.1 when clicking the casted objects. But this is why I tried 1.7.1. I also tried 1.8.0.

Answer (score 0):

### I have found the cause and a solution, but at the bottom line this seems to me like a Gradle bug.

In my app's build.gradle, in the dependencies block, I am including a dependency to my own library:

```
implementation project(path: ':mylib')
```

AFAIU this should not have and does not have any influence on the compilation of anything else in my main project (except where directly using mylib).

mylib is old and serves specifc purpose and generally I have no reason to update it. Its build.gradle has this dependency:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.1'
```

This is causing the lint issue.
Luckily, I could ugrade to `'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'` without any other change.