# AppCompatActivity not recognising registerForActivityResult

Tags: android, android-appcompat, appcompatactivity

For some reason `AppCompatActivity` doesn't recognize `registerForActivityResult`.

The weird thing is that `AppCompatActivity` is defined as an extension of `FragmentActivity` which in turn extends `ComponentActivity`.

Now, `ComponentActivity` does have the method `registerForActivityResult`.

From what I can see, it seems that `AppCompatActivity` is somehow extending an old version of `FragmentActivity` (from fragment-1.0.0) which, in turn, extends an old version of `ComponentActivity` (from core-1.0.0).
However, if I use `ComponentActivity` or `FragmentActivity` directly it uses the right one.

I am guessing it is something in my `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.4.0"

implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.3.0"
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'
implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.5.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.4.0'
implementation("androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0")

// optional - RxJava2 support
implementation("androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences-rxjava2:1.0.0")

// optional - RxJava3 support
implementation("androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences-rxjava3:1.0.0")

implementation project(':WeFiUiLibs')
implementation project(':WeFiUtil')

implementation "com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0"
implementation("io.insert-koin:koin-core:3.5.0")
implementation("io.insert-koin:koin-android:3.5.0")
implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:5.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.4'
implementation("androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.8.0")
```

The result is the same whether I leave the `appcompat` line in or remove it.

Edit:

I did a full dependencies list and got the following line in several places:

```
androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 -> 1.3.6 (*)
```

I'm guessing that that's okay and is saying that `1.0.0` is being replaced by `1.3.6` though I have no idea what `(*)` means.

Comment: Do the modules you have as `project` dependencies  (`:WeFiUiLibs` and `:WeFiUtils`) use an old version of AppCompat? This sounds similar to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77355586/1676363)

Comment: Nope. However, the problem is not with AppCompat itself. It is using the correct one (1.6.1). The problem is that it pulls in the wrong version of FragmentActivity